# como modificar multiples valores en un array de objectos en mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

estoy tratando de hacer un chat y para el sistema de mensajes leidos, quiero que cuando la persona entre todos los mensajes que estan en falso se cambien a true esto es lo que llevo de momento pero no logro hacer el query de mongodb,
necesito que cambie a true todos los mensajes que esten en read false y que el usuario que los cambie no tenga la misma id que ese mensaje
ejemplo si el user A envio el mensaje que no se cambie a true si es el

```js
export const saveReadMsgs = async (chatId) => {
  try{
    const updatedChat = await chatModel.updateOne(
      {
        id:chatId
      },
      { 
          $set: { 
            "messages" : {
              "read":true
            }
          } 
      },
    );
    console.log(updatedChat);
  }catch(e){
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

adjunto un ejemplo del objeto

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63acbf00903200d01c44aecd"
  },
  "users": [
    {
      "$oid": "62e3df964db2354837e3461c"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "62e3df964db2354847e3463c"
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "user": "62e3df964db2354847e3463c",
      "text": "texto de prueba 1",
      "time": "December 28th 2022, 6:11 pm",
      "read": true
    },
    {
      "user": "62e3df964db2354847e3463c",
      "text": "hi",
      "time": "December 28th 2022, 6:12 pm",
      "read": true
    },
    {
      "user": "62e3df964db2354847e3463c",
      "text": "texto de prueba 2",
      "time": "December 28th 2022, 6:12 pm",
      "read": true
    },
    {
      "user": "62e3df964db2354847e3463c",
      "text": "texto de prueba  ",
      "time": "December 28th 2022, 6:34 pm",
      "read": false
    },
    {
      "user": "62e3df964db2354837e3461c",
      "text": "texto de prueba",
      "time": "December 28th 2022, 6:40 pm",
      "read": false
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1672265472416"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1672267233905"
    }
  }
}
```

la cosa es que quiero que modifique nadamas los que estan en true no que cambie siempre todo a false  como podria lograr esto ?

Answer (score 0):

Entonces lo puedes hacer así:

```
const updatedChat = await chatModel.update(
      {
        id:chatId
      },
      { 
          $set: {
              "messages.$[e].read": true
          }
      },
      {
        arrayFilters: [
          {
            "e.user": { $ne: "tu_user_id" },
            "e.read": false
          }
        ],
      }
    )
```

Para eso se usa el operador $[] (operador posicional filtrado): https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

Donde especificamos un identificador (en este caso e) y luego mediante el `arrayFilters` decimos las condiciones que debe tener ese identificador para que sea cambiado.
En este caso, especificamos que el usuario no sea el que consulta (tu reemplazas "tu_user_id" por el valor correspondiente), y también especificamos que el mensaje esté marcado como read:false.

Te dejo un ejemplo en mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/SV4VN5dE9vy